# Group objects in List by property in object that is List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a List of objects (name of object is NGramm) and object has a property - list of strings (name of property is RawNGramWords). There is another property of RawNGramWords - NGramCount - that is the number of the objects in LIST with the same RawNGramWords (the same lists of strings in different NGramm). So if there are for example 3 objects (NGramm) in the List with the same RawNGramWords I need to get only one NGramm object with NGramCount  property = 3. Other 2 objects with the same RawNGramWords lists should be deleted from the List. 
I used this code:

```
public static List<NGramm> CountNWordsInNGrams(List<NGramm> listOfNgramms)
    {
        List<int> indexesOfNGramsInListToDelete = new List<int>(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfNgramms.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < listOfNgramms.Count; j++)
            {
                bool areEquivalent = !listOfNgramms[i].RawNGramWords.Except(listOfNgramms[j].RawNGramWords).Any();
                if(areEquivalent == true)
                {
                    indexesOfNGramsInListToDelete.Add(i);
                    listOfNgramms[j].NGramCount = listOfNgramms[j].NGramCount + listOfNgramms[i].NGramCount + 1;

                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = listOfNgramms.Count; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (indexesOfNGramsInListToDelete.Contains(i))
            {
                listOfNgramms.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        return listOfNgramms;
    }
```

The speed of this method is very slow. (It counts NGramCount with error - but on the whole it doesn't matter due to the slow speed - I need another way to find the same lists of strings in these objects). 
So - is there any way to use group by to count the objects with the same List (RawNGramWords) with LINQ?
Thank you

Comment: so if i get this correctly, you only need the one of each `NGramm` object that has a unique `NGramCount` inside the list?

Comment: @Timothy Groote Yes. Or I need like a dictionary where key is object and values - count of them (if they have the same List of strings property). So I need to count the object with the same lists of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will group a `List` of `NGramm` objects by their `RawNGramWords` property into a `Dictionary<string[], List<NGramm>>`.

The key (`string[]`) of the dictionary is the `RawNGramWords` property of the `NGramm` objects.

Assuming your `NGramm` class looks somewhat like this :

```
    class NGramm
    {
        public string[] RawNGramWords;
        public int NGramCount;
    }
```

You could do this with a `List<NGramm>` :

```
List<NGramm> listOfNgramms;

Dictionary<string[], List<NGramm>> groupedResults = (from ngramm in listOfNgramms
                group ngramm by ngramm.RawNGramWords
                into groupedNGramms
                select groupedNGramms).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

On a side note, the code you posted is doing a few things for which i don't entirely understand the reason (re-iterating the tail of the first iteration for example). which is slowing it down.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do ToLookup instead of ToDictionary()?

Comment: @mstaessen that depends if you want to edit the resulting set after the grouping.

Comment: Thank you @Timothy Groote ! I also understood that i can just concatenate list of strings in one string (as another object property) and group by this string: var dict = listOfNgramms.GroupBy(w => w.ConcatatedRawNGramWords).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            dict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Value descending select entry).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);

Comment: @AlexeyRumin you could do that. but i doubt you'd gain much in the way of performance. I figured that would just add to the complexity.